# Как сворачивать предыдущий развернутый блок если открывать следующий и наоборот? JQuery

Tags: jquery

Один блок по клику открывается и по клику закрывается, но если был открытый уже и клацнуть на второй, как закрыть первый? И наоборот.

Чтобы всегда показывать тот блок на который клацнули хоть туда сюда клацать показывать только тот на который последний раз клацнули, а предыдущий при этом плавно также закрывать(если был открыт).

Выполните код, что-то там по разному работает)

```js
$('body').on('click', '.prod-li a', function () {
        $(this).closest(".prod-li").find(".blok").not("." + $(this).data("blok") ).slideUp();
        $("." + $(this).data("blok")).slideToggle();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article class="prod-li">
  <div class="prod-li-inner">
    <div class="prod-li-info">
      <div class="prod-li-favorites">
          <a data-blok="blok2" href="#" class="open-info">                          <span>Написать</span>
          </a>
      </div>
      <p class="prod-li-information">
          <a data-blok="blok1" href="#"  class="open-info">                        <span>Позвонить</span>
          </a>
                                            
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blok blok1" style="display: none;">
    показать телефон
  </div>
  <div class="blok blok2" style="display: none;">
    показать майл
  </div>
</article>
<article class="prod-li">
  <div class="prod-li-inner">
    <div class="prod-li-info">
      <div class="prod-li-favorites">
          <a data-blok="blok2" href="#" class="open-info">                          <span>Написать</span>
          </a>
      </div>
      <p class="prod-li-information">
          <a data-blok="blok1" href="#"  class="open-info">                        <span>Позвонить</span>
          </a>
                                            
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blok blok1" style="display: none;">
    показать телефон
  </div>
  <div class="blok blok2" style="display: none;">
    показать майл
  </div>
</article>
<article class="prod-li">
  <div class="prod-li-inner">
    <div class="prod-li-info">
      <div class="prod-li-favorites">
          <a data-blok="blok2" href="#" class="open-info">                          <span>Написать</span>
          </a>
      </div>
      <p class="prod-li-information">
          <a data-blok="blok1" href="#"  class="open-info">                        <span>Позвонить</span>
          </a>
                                            
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blok blok1" style="display: none;">
    показать телефон
  </div>
  <div class="blok blok2" style="display: none;">
    показать майл
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('body').on('click', '.prod-li a', function() {
  $(this).closest(".prod-li").find(".blok").not("." + $(this).data("blok")).slideUp();
  $(this).closest(".prod-li").find(".blok." + $(this).data("blok")).slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="prod-li">
  <a data-blok="blok1" href="#">Блок1</a>
  <a data-blok="blok2" href="#">Блок2</a>
  <a data-blok="blok3" href="#">Блок3</a>

  <div class="blok blok1" style="display:none">Показать blok1</div>
  <div class="blok blok2" style="display:none">Показать blok2</div>
  <div class="blok blok3" style="display:none">Показать blok3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: большое спасибо, только я один нюанс еще не нашел, я обновил код смотрите у меня несколько экземпляров, поэтому если я открываю первый блок то открывается этот блок у всех этот первый блок как тут быть?

Comment: получается на странице может быть много этих блоков
not("." + $(this).data("blok") ).slideUp();
поэтому кода он исключает то все эти блоки к примеру blok1 все и остаются и соответственно открываются все где остался blok1

Comment: добавил я только data-blok="blok_<?php $article->id?>" 
потому как 
@foreach($articles as $article)
<article class="prod-li"></article >
@endforeach